# Eslint, Jslint or other for React lifecycle methods?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, eslint

It seems every linter I try to use sees the react lifecycle methods as unused. Is there a way to configure (preferably eslint) to avoid warnings about the lifecycle methods?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react Did you check this out?

Comment: Yah, doesn't work. Enforces style but still throws warning about unused methods.

Comment: Are you using es6 syntax or es5. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following eslint configuration. We are following es6 syntax.

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "globals": {
    "__DEV__": true,
    "jest" : true,
    "describe" :true,
    "it":true,
    "beforeEach":true,
    "afterEach":true,
    "expect":true
  }
}
```

The above syntax extends airbnb style guideline. You can find it [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react).
Their guideline also talks about simple javascript also, [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). My eslint configuration even informs even informs me about misspelled lifecycle methods like typing `componentDidReceiveProps`. You can override things which you do not want or prefer other syntax.